# Start cfn-init in Ubuntu instance with cloudformation (yaml)

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I try to start the cfn-init with:

```
Fn::Base64: !Sub | 
  #!/bin/bash
  sudo apt-get -y install python-setuptools
  mkdir aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest
  curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz | tar xz -C aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest --strip-components 1
  sudo easy_install aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest
  sudo /usr/local/bin/cfn-init --stack !Ref 'AWS::StackName' --resource xxx --region !Ref 'AWS::Region'
```

The first steps work. I can access the instance and `cfn-init` is installed. When I execute the `cfn-init --stack..` command inside my ec2 instance it works fine when I hardcode the values for stackname and region.

How to make it work in the `yaml` script? It seems it can not read the values for StackName and region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `!Sub` you need to wrap your variables with `${}` instead of using `!Ref`

Try this

```
Fn::Base64: !Sub | 
  #!/bin/bash
  sudo apt-get -y install python-setuptools
  mkdir aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest
  curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz | tar xz -C aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest --strip-components 1
  sudo easy_install aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest
  sudo /usr/local/bin/cfn-init --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource xxx --region ${AWS::Region}
```

> If you specify template parameter names or resource logical IDs, such
>   as ${InstanceTypeParameter}, AWS CloudFormation returns the same
>   values as if you used the Ref intrinsic function. If you specify
>   resource attributes, such as ${MyInstance.PublicIp}, AWS
>   CloudFormation returns the same values as if you used the Fn::GetAtt
>   intrinsic function.

For more details check [AWS - Fn::Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html)

Comment: I tried with ubuntu. didn'\t work. any solution?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
        UserData:
          Fn::Base64: !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash

            sudo apt-get install -y build-essential python3-pip
            sudo pip3 install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-py3-latest.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Amazon published a few different example scripts to do this on various different operating systems.

Original question about installing helper scripts on Ubuntu: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/install-cloudformation-scripts

Direct link to Ubuntu templates:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/solutions/OperatingSystems

Answer (score 0):

```
Fn::Base64: !Sub | 
  #!/bin/bash
  sudo apt-get -y install python-setuptools
  mkdir aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest
  curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz | tar xz -C aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest --strip-components 1
  sudo easy_install aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest
  sudo /usr/local/bin/cfn-init --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource xxx --region ${AWS::Region}
```

IF easy_install didn't work for ubuntu 18.04 then use this following command:

```
python /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_install.py aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest
```

Answer (score 0):

If the easy_install command not found then try this it works for me

```
"UserData": {
  "Fn::Base64": { "Fn::Join":["", [
    "#!/bin/bash\n",
    "apt-get update\n",
    "apt-get install -y python-setuptools\n",
    "mkdir -p /opt/aws/bin\n",
    "apt-get install -y wget\n",
    "wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-py3-latest.tar.gz\n",
    "python3 -m easy_install --script-dir /opt/aws/bin aws-cfn-bootstrap-py3-latest.tar.gz\n",
    "/usr/local/bin/cfn-init --stack ", { "Ref":"AWS::StackName" }, " --resource WebServer", " --region ", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
    "\n",
    "/usr/local/bin/cfn-signal --exit-code $? '", { "Ref" : "WaitHandle" }, "'\n"
  ]]}
}
```